# How to dedicate RAM to Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ram

**Problem**

I've been working with software called Leaflet, PostGRES and Geoserver, which I use to load in milions of datapoints... Well... that's what I'm supposed to do. Loading these points using GeoJSON and Javascript utilizes the RAM memory. Exceeding a certain amount of points actually crashes the web application. In Taskmanager I can see that Google Chrome uses more RAM, but there's still some available RAM left.

I am aware of the fact that some applications can utilize a set amount of RAM.

**In short**

Can I dedicate a set amount of RAM that Google Chrome can utilize. For example, 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. It's an offline computer as it's a data carrier so it's running Windows 10 1803